# Can I share resource file across the webserver?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, resources, webserver, resx

I have a 2 web application built in MVC 5 and 2 application built in PHP. I want a way to share resource file across all the web applications. i.e create a single file say strings.resx and use this in all the other web application.

This is basically for localization. All the 4 web applications are the part of the same system. So it should share the same file across all the applications. If the label for 'Enter first name' is changed in one application to 'First name' then we would not have to change it in all the application. Changing that string in one file will change it for all application. And also for language change it would be helpful.

Also in MVC projects change to the resource file requires compiling the project. But I want it in such a way that the change should require compiling the projects.

Is it even possible?

I have tried creating a `App_GlobalResources` folder and adding resource in it. This helps in changing the resource without compiling the web applications project but works only for a single application. I would want this to happen for all 4 web applications.

The common file will have all the label names, error messages (for javascript) and all the text in the web application.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gettext` for `PHP` and `ngetText` for the `.NET` platforms. https://github.com/neris/NGettext

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by using  [I18N](https://www.nuget.org/packages/I18N/).

Add the I18N nuget package to .net MVC project with .po files.